# Having trouble converting json to abi encoding

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, ropsten, abi, verify

I'm trying to convert the following json to abi code using https://abi.hashex.org/

```
[
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_greeting",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "greet",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_greeting",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "setGreeting",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    }
  ]
```

However this site doesn't seem to generate the abi code nor does it explain why it isn't generating it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the constructor  value of _greeting[image]